# as3 extract class reference from swc

Tags: apache-flex, air, swc

Does anyone know how to extract a class reference from an SWC file?  I know I can right click / "Go to definition", and view the class definition.

I need to extract these for each class in an SWC.  Can anyone provide a method to do so automatically?

Best,
Frank

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Flash Develop however have access to FlashBuilder

Comment: I am trying to understand the question, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. What do you mean with "extract a class reference". Showing code is probably the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what do you mean saying "extract".
If you need to use some class from SWC, just set this SWC as a library for your project in your IDE.
If you are talking about viewing source code, that's almost impossible, because SWC is an archive with compiled classes (swf). You may use flash decompilers to get some source code from it.
BTW, IntelliJ IDEA can parse swc and show you fields and methods' ptototypes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to extract classes from the Flex SDK itself, you can [grab the entire project using SVN](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Get+Source+Code) or browse their [online class summary documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/class-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

A list of the classes packaged into the swc is available from the `catalog.xml` file in the swc.

Rename the .swc to a .zip file, and you can access it.

However, if you want the actual methods in each class, I'm afraid you're out of luck.